# Using ajaxStop callback to set doument.location

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a number of jquery asynchronous calls being called in a loop. At the end of the last call, I want the page to refresh to show the results after the call. What I have isn't working. I would appreciate some help on either why its not working or a better solution!

Thanks.

```
var ajaxCount = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {


    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        ajaxCount = 1;
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        ajaxCount = 0;
    });
}

function(){
    for(x loops){
        $ajax({...});
    }
    while (ajaxCount != 0) { }
    document.location = applicationRoot + 'Qc.mvc/ViewQc/' + batchId + '/1';

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.ajaxStop()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) fires when all concurrent ajax requests have finished, so you can just use it directly, for example:

```
function(){
  $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    window.location.href = applicationRoot + 'Qc.mvc/ViewQc/' + batchId + '/1';
  });
  $ajax({...});
}
```

If you need the count of active AJAX requests, jQuery already maintains this, it just doesn't publicize it...it's actually what's used to determine when to fire `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` events.  You can accedd it via `$.active`.  In jQuery 1.5+ it's being moved to `$.ajax.active`.

Comment: The problem is that I have other ajax calls on the page which I don't want a refresh after. Its only one particular set of ajax calls which should trigger a  page refresh.

Comment: @shaw2thefloor - That's why I'd bind *inside* the function you care about...you can bind/unbind when you want, e.g. `$(document).unbind('ajaxStop')` would stop listening for the event.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put `window.location.href = ....` in the callback function of that one particular ajax call?

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    ajaxCount = ajaxCount + 1;
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    ajaxCount = ajaxCount - 1;
    if (ajaxCount == 0 && check if they're all fired)
            window.location.href = ...
});
```

Comment: As I understand it, there are many calls, and he wants to redirect when they're *all* finished.

Comment: I would then suggest something like this: 

    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        ajaxCount = ajaxCount + 1;
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        ajaxCount = ajaxCount - 1;
        if (ajaxCount == 0)
                window.location.href = ...
    });

Comment: I tried that. I think the problem is in the while loop. It seems like it gets to the while loop and then never runs ajaxStop(); Sorry, I just changed the code above to make it more representative of what is going on.